# Review completed by one person in First Posts queue?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

I've came across this [review](https://superuser.com/review/first-posts/431438) which I wanted to flag it as not answer, but after it was hanging awhile in my open tab, when I've back to it, it says:

> **Review completed** 24 mins ago:
>
> x reviewed this 24 mins ago: No Action Needed
>     Next

This is not definitely the answer (rather 'I've this too' or a comment), however this post has been marked already as: 'Review completed' despite only one person had a look at it?

Is that an expected behaviour for First Posts queue?

Update: It actually got picked-up again in [here](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/431445) (Low Quality Posts queue).

Comment: strange. the flag timeline says it was never reviewed by the user in question as mentioned on the review page.

Comment: It's almost as if the post was "moved" from the First Posts review queue to the Low Quality Posts review queue after @JoshR flagged it... Is it possible that after the post was marked as deleted, from the Low Quality queue, it was automatically closed in the First Posts queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only 1 no action needed review required to clear the post from the first post review queue (whether or not this is a good idea is being discussed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266027/make-three-no-action-needed-required-to-remove-something-from-first-posts-and)). Your review never came through since the other reviewer was faster than you.